# Dual boot linux/windows GRUB

Tags: boot

I have a ASUS computer and i'm trying to install ubuntu. I have 2 hard disk, so i installed ubuntu on the second one (where there is no windows 7..), format the partition of 100go in ext4 , and choose at boot sector the partition of the 1st HDD where it was written "windows loader" but had an error so i choose the root of the 1stHDD but still no choice at the boot of the computer, windows boot and no grub...
How can i fix it?

Comment: Firstly fix the Windows botloader, then fix grub do not install it on a partition on the second disk (as you did) install it ON the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably about the boot-order of devices in your BIOS.
Check it to put your second hard-disk as the first checked at start-up.

You should try to repair grub : http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tutoriel/comment_restaurer_grub

For those who don't speak french : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: In the BIOS, I can see 2HDD but they're both the same, apparently it's because of RAID..
And if i do so, the computer will always boot on linux as it does actually with windows, no?

Comment: No, it won't because Linux will show GRUB to let you choose the operating system.
"it's because of RAID" You're using raid but you put an OS on only one disk ? Is it possible ?? You sure about the RAID part ?

Comment: No, not sure about the raid part but sure about the fact that the second HDD is not available in bios choices..

Comment: Set the second hard disk as the first disk in the hard-disk panel, your BIOS is probably ordering items by type, and you can choose one item of each type. Look at that.
For the raid, you're probably not using it.

Comment: I'm gonna try it. 
But i choose the root of the 1st HDD at amorcage sector, so grub should be installed there, no? (sorry for the english, i'm french..)

Comment: (Don't worry, I'm french too ;) ) When you said "the root" you said something like "/dev/sda" or something like "/dev/sda1" ?

Comment: yes it's that, /dev/sda :) 
If I remember well, i first choose /dev/sda1 where there was windows loader but it didn't worked, so i took /dev/sda

Comment: Get a look to the link I've added to my first post, you should try the boot-repair (look at the link "Réparateur de Démarrage" in the french topic) inside a live-cd or something like that

Comment: Ok i'm gonna take a look and try it, what should I put in the different input who are proposed?

Comment: That's a good question, I never used such of tools.
By the way, you could try to force on "/dev/sda" or something like that. Try to place it on sda, if it don't work try on sdb so.

Comment: it's okay, i used a boot reparator and i can now see grub.. But if i try to hibernate from linux i have a black screen with a white message like "[drm]"..

Comment: Set the answered flag by checking the awnser, and open another question : another question , another thread ;)